# How does C# do dynamic binding?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I have this question about c# language's dynamic binding behavior.

Consider the following object hierarchy:

> object
>
> > System.Windows.Forms.Control
> >
> > > ClassA
> > >
> > > > ClassB
> > > >
> > > > > MyClass

There might be additional classes in between but these are the ones we should consider. Object and Control classes are .NET Framework classes. ClassA and ClassB are third party library classes and MyClass is ... well, my class.
I've overridden "Control"s TabStop property in MyClass. The property might be overridden somewhere else in the hierarchy, but I don't think that really matters.
(MyClass is in another assembly which is a vb.net project)

```
Public Overrides Property TabStop As Boolean
    Get
        Return MyBase.TabStop
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        MyBase.TabStop = value
    End Set
End Property
```

And last, please consider the following code. Note that some of the objects in myControlCollection is of type MyClass, others are not.:

```
        foreach (Control c in myControlCollection)
        {
            if (c is ClassA)
            {
                if (((ClassA)c).Properties.ReadOnly) c.TabStop = false;
            }
        }
```

Now comes the question:
I've set a breakpoint in MyClass's TabStop property's setter method.

The breakpoint is not hit for ANY object in the collection if the code runs as given above.

If I change the line as...

> ((ClassA)c).TabStop = false;

... visual studio hits the breakpoint in MyClass declaration.

This confuses me. Why is not the breakpoint hit when the property is called through a variable of type "Control". Even though the variable is of type Control, the actual object is of type MyClass, so I believe the breakpoint should be hit.
And second, if it does not hit when called through a variable of type Control, why does it hit when I cast the variable to ClassA. I am not casting it to MyClass, I am casting it to a base class, which probably has its own implementation of TabStop, or maybe inherits from Control. Either case, it is not my code.

Can anybody please explain this behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have not actually overriden the `TabStop` property, because [it is not virtual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabstop.aspx).

*What you have done is "hidden" it by creating another property with the same name*. Therefore, a different property setter is executed when you try to set `Control.TabStop` here:

```
// The static type of c is Control!
if (((ClassA)c).Properties.ReadOnly) c.TabStop = false;
```

And when you set it here:

```
// The static type is now ClassA
((ClassA)c).TabStop = false;
```

When you refer to the property, the compiler resolves the name using **static** binding because it is not virtual. For that reason if you do not cast the object to something more derived than `Control`, you will not see your own code run.

**Update:** This still leaves some open questions:

1. Why does the compiler bind to `MyControl.TabStop` if the static type of the variable is `ClassA`? Shouldn't it still bind to `Control.TabStop`?
2. Why does the compiler let you write `Public Overrides Property TabStop As Boolean` if `Control.TabStop` is not virtual?

We know that there has to be *some* class in the hierarchy between `Control` and `MyControl` with a virtual `TabStop` property (otherwise `Overrides` on `MyControl.TabStop` would be a compiler error). We also know that `ClassA.TabStop` ends up binding to `MyControl.TabStop`. Assuming that there is no other class in the hierarchy between `Control` and `ClassA`, there is only one logical explanation: class `ClassA` defines a virtual `TabStop` property that `Shadows` `Control.TabStop`.

Comment: I'll add that this confusion is "normal" for people that come from Java experience: there all non static methods are virtual by default (unless you mark them with private or final).

Comment: Ok, your answer makes sense for the first part. Thanks for that. But it does not explain the second part. If I make the assigment like "  ((ClassA)c).TabStop = false  ", the code in MyClass is run. Why?

Comment: @e-mre: That's a very good question. Possibly `ClassA` `Shadows` the property `TabStop` with a new virtual property, which `MyClass` then overrides? Can't say without looking at the definitions for all classes in the hierarchy.

Comment: @xanatos ... I think Java approach makes more sense. .NET behavior just does not fit the idea of polymorphism in my head.  Any user of a class expects that class to behave like it always does, not matter how it is called. Why would I need to know where a property is declared? who overrides it? who hides it? Any idea why .NET chose this way, or what is the benefit of this approach?

Comment: @jon: I went through the documentation and that is exactly the case. ClassA hides the property with a new one which is virtual.

Comment: @e-mre: In the meantime, I updated the answer because that's the only logical explanation.

Comment: @e-mre Sense, like beauty, is in the eye of the beholder. There isn't any "better" way. On memory-starved systems (embedded apps) non virtual methods are better.